# solr asks more and more rows from shards

Tags: performance, solr

I am having performance issues after solr6 upgrade. I have multiple nodes in the cluster and direct queries to one of them with `shards=[list of hosts]` which takes care of submitting queries to all the shards and aggregating the results. All the original queries have rows=200.

I have found that many logs with `distrib=false` have large rows value. e.g., values like: 1200, 2200, 3200, 4200, ... .

What is triggering it?  What am I doing wrong to cause this behavior.

Comment: What does your query look like? There might be features that require Solr to look at more than the given number of documents, although I'm not sure what that would be .. Have you made sure that the distrib=false-logs you're seeing are attached to the same query that you initially made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that i was not paying attention to the `start` parameter. 
I found that the 'primary' node is asking for very large count of `rows` from shard nodes when the `start=` is a large value.